# Flexbox: Keep element as last element before flex-wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to keep an element in the first row (as last element) of a list of wrapping elements. I know that this is possible using JS, but I am wondering if there is a CSS only solution to this. The closest I can get is putting the element in a separate container, but this results in an unwanted space between the elements:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left > div {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background: blue;
}

.right > div {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>Left 1</div>
    <div>Left 2</div>
    <div>Left 3</div>
    <div>Left 4</div>
    <div>Left 5</div>
    <div>Left 6</div>
    <div>Left 7</div>
    <div>Left 8</div>
    <div>Left 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>More</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, the red element should directly follow the last element in the first row of blue elements while the blue elements wrap inside their container. Is this possible with pure CSS?

Comment: If you add `flex-grow: 1;` to `.left > div` it allows the children to stretch but I don't know if that's what you want. You can also try using a CSS grid and set the specific col/row for the `more` button but I'm also not sure if that's what you want

Comment: Basically, no. not with standard flexbox. This sounds more like a `float` issue which, of course, does not work in a flexbox.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with flexbox while using `flex-wrap` because flexbox is use basically to make a webpage responsive and your code seems to working in relevant manner.  It will make a white-gap till when the div doesn't not fitting properly. But after a perfect fit the gap vanishes

Answer (score 1):

With CSS-Grid this is possible but there are caveats. You have to specify a default width for your children and if there are not enough children to fill a row you may get gaps again.

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JjNMEby?editors=1100)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, auto));
}

.container div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background: blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container .right {
  grid-column-end: -1;
  grid-row: 1;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Left 1</div>
  <div>Left 2</div>
  <div>Left 3</div>
  <div>Left 4</div>
  <div>Left 5</div>
  <div>Left 6</div>
  <div>Left 7</div>
  <div>Left 8</div>
  <div>Left 9</div>
  <div class="right">More</div>
  <div>Left 10</div>
  <div>Left 11</div>
  <div>Left 12</div>
</div>
```